# Can I put activity final node directly after Synchronization node?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I want to put activity final node after Parallelization node.

[image]

Am I correct in putting activity final node, or better use flow final node in one of the activity node?

Comment: why do you supposed you cannot ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: yes. Your acrivity will end upon both of the two parallel actions have completed which is probably your intention. It's also possible to put flow finals after each of them but I think that this way it's more clear.

p. 386 of UML 2.5:

> A FlowFinalNode is a FinalNode that terminates a flow. All tokens accepted by a FlowFinalNode are destroyed. This has no effect on other flows in the Activity.

and

> An ActivityFinalNode is a FinalNode that stops all flows in an Activity...